# How to see the true value of a DECIMAL field?

Tags: mysql

Is there a query which will return the true value of a numeric datatype like DECIMAL when you specified a display width on column creation, given that the true width is greater than the display width?

Comment: Any example of a 'false' value of a DECIMAL?

Comment: When inputting a value for a DECIMAL(18,3) of 123.4567, the true value will be 123.4567, but all attempts to display it will result in 123.456, the false value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a display width, it's number of digits to store

So the data is actually trunc if it doesn't fit

Comment: So DECIMAL type doesn't support display width? Got it.

Comment: @Nag Hammadi: nope, it is just a *number of digits to store*. Everything that doesn't fit it won't be stored at all